# What are these files that keep popping up on my raspberry pi?

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've been trying to compile opencv on my raspberry pi 4 running raspberry pi OS.

While doing so I've found large numbers of files with seemingly random names in my working directories, for example, in /usr/lib:

```
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep 12 03:00 st1iFUlb
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep  7 05:34 st1lfaje
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep  7 05:34 st3ktIDg
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep 12 03:00 st61kqLp
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep  7 05:34 st8bW59e
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep 12 03:00 st9eZ33h
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep 12 03:00 st9kqYPR
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep 12 03:00 stAll2vg
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep 12 03:00 stavkS4g
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep 12 03:00 stdMWans
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep 12 03:00 stfMrI1a
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep 12 03:00 stIJJNmX
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep 12 03:00 stoljZik
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep  7 05:34 stP0islj
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep  7 05:34 stqtW0TK
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep 12 03:00 stStUvE2
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep  7 05:34 stTQF2Ne
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep 12 03:00 stTT96Tj
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep  7 05:34 sttYNqFk
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep 12 03:00 stUMgLkw
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep 12 03:00 stVZ107S
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep 12 03:00 stWTYtVd
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep  7 05:34 stZrqQtd
-rw-------  1 root root        0 Sep 12 03:00 stZUJwPn
```

Any idea what these are? I assume they're some kind of cruft generated during compilation and installation of libraries. They all start with st, but I don't know what that would signify.